Why Groups are one-object categories?
I understand why the group composition taken as the objects and the morphism, taken as the group elements, works as a one-object category (and satisfies the respective properties). But will it not be more "intuitive" to define it the other way round (e.g. the morphism as the group operation and group elements as the object)? What is the advantage (or correctness) of defining groups this way?

" the group operation taken as the objects" Huh? The group operation is composition (of morphisms).

You may be interested in monoidal categories. They categorify monoids in a different way. Also 2-groups.

You could maybe take elements of $G$ to be objects, and morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}(x, y)$ to be ${ g\in G \mid g \cdot x = y }$.  Though since that's always a singleton, the resulting category ends up being equivalent to the category with one object and one morphism, so it's not that interesting.  You might get more interesting results with the same construction for $G$-sets, or starting with a monoid instead of a group; though I haven't seen that construction for a category studied before so I'm a bit doubtful.
